# Is there any way to url decode variable on Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, urldecode

I'm looking for a way to url decode a string variable on Freemarker.

For example, consider the following string: attr=hello+world%3F .
Expected result: hello world?

Any simple way to get this result? somewhat like ${attr?urlDecode}? I could not find anything online.

Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for same answer, this is most probably solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455730/in-freemarker-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, FreeMarker only has built in support for URL encoding, not decoding. You can however solve this by creating your own directive for URI-decoding.

Something like this: https://gist.github.com/lazee/285d206470fb6076d262

Here is a small test class that shows you how you can add the directive as a shared variable, and how to use it in a template: https://gist.github.com/lazee/f5c524b3c7bebf68955e

Comment: Use this tester instead : https://gist.github.com/lazee/1307b7b05ea52f793db7 . Had a leftover of some other test code in the previous Tester.java

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. But it looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function built in (2.3.23).

In what scenario is it needed?