# In freemarker, how to convert a string to utf-8 encoding?

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to convert a string encoding to utf-8 in freemarker script. 
Is there a way to encode a freemarker string encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by UTF-8 encoding you mean percentage escaping, like `példa` to `p%C3%A9lda`, then it's done as `myString?url` (or if it's more familiar this way: `${myString?url}`). However, the charset used by `?url` depends on the `url_encoding_charset` FreeMarker configuration setting, which should be set to `UTF-8` in your application. (It's also possible to specify the charset directly, like in `myString?url('UTF-8')`.)

Documentation: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_url