# Issues with Parameters containg whitespaces

Tags: freemarker

i've the following situation with Freemarker.

When returning to a page in .ftl i send from Java a parameter to the url, similar to "AAA% BBB@DDD.COM", in Java it is ok.

When looking at the Url it does instead Write : "AAA%25+BBB@DDD.COM" And then with the following code:

```
<#if myCase??>
    value = ${user}
</#if>
```

It does write in my html field "AAA%" but not the remaining.

How can i try to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After further investigations i do see the code i put before does write this on the Html:

```
value="AAA%" BBB@CCC.com=""
```

EDIT2: Let'see if i can give you more informations, first of, here's the relevant Java code :

```
Map mapping = new HashMap();
if(user != null && !user.isEmpty()){
 mapping.put("user",user); //EG: AAA% BBB@DDD.COM (Checked in debug)
}
```

I have an URL similar to : mysite.xx?user=AAA%25+BBB@DDD.COM so the user it's attached as query param of the url.

I do need to reuse the "user" param to repopulate the Form field relative to the username, this is not a valid email i know, but an alias system already installed by the customer does the aliasing system this way.

Comment: Would be nice to have the part of **Java-code** where you set the _variable/model_ as well the **full template (FTL)**. Which output do you use, HTML?

Comment: Yes, i do use HTML as output, i cannot put the full template but i can give more snippet when necessary.

Comment: Please post the lines from Java where you define the value to _user_ variable; see [mcve]. Is it defined as a String `String user = "AAA% BBB@DDD.COM";` or as URL like `URL user = new URL( "AAA%25+BBB@DDD.COM");`  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What could be the cause of the problem

Given your template:

```
<#if myCase??>
    value = ${user}
</#if>
```

Output written by Freemarker in output-mode HTML results in following:

```
value = AAA% BBB@DDD.COM
```

Freemarker does not understand that (from your context) the value of `user` should be an attribute-value (assignment). Instead it treats the contents of string `user` as HTML itself (this could be complete HTML-source as input-field, single tags, etc.). It simply pastes the contents of the *model* at the  position in your template where you have set the variable-interpolation `${user}`.

The Freemarker-result is no valid HTML (attribute-value pair), because each attribute should adhere some naming-conventions (i.e. no special-characters). When the attribute has a value, it is followed by an equal-sign and this followed by the value enclosed in double-quotes.

So most **browsers convert your result into a valid HTML** attribute - actually two attributes: `value="AAA%"` and `BBB@CCC.com=""`. Opened the output-HTML in Firefox, you will see this in **Inspector** (NOT IN the raw source-view):

```
<input type="text" value="AAA%" bbb@ddd.com="">
```

#### What is not the cause

FreeMarker is [auto-escaping](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html#dgui_misc_autoescaping_movalues) (escpecially when in OutputMode HTML) when it writes the final HTML.

> @**ddekany** Thanks for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/96642869?noredirect=1) ! It made me reproduce and discover the real cause.

#### URL encoding/decoding

In Java you could even encode the string variable `user`. So it converts `%` (i.e. *percent-sign* followed by *space*) into `%25+` which is valid to be used inside an URL.

Run [this java snippet](https://ideone.com/lpMzIY) online on IDEONE to the effects of URL-encoding and URL-decoding.

## Solutions

Use either of these solutions to get desired output by fixing the HTML-attribute value-assignment in your template:

#### (1) use double-quotes:

```
   <#if myCase??>
       value="${user}"
   </#if>
```

#### (2) use some built-ins to transform the plain string-output:

Use some of FreeMarker's **built-ins** for strings. In your case you could append [**?url**](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_url) to the variable-name and use **double-quotes** around your *variable-interpolation* within your template, e.g.:

```
   <#if myCase??>
       href="mailto:${user?url}"
   </#if>
```

### Caution: validate URL or email-address (even parts of it) as early as possible

`BBB@DDD.COM` is a valid email-address. But `%` and *whitespaces* are not allowed inside an email-address.

On the other side `@` is typically not part of an URL, except as part inside a **query-param** value. But your `user` (URL) does not start with `http://` etc.

So depending on the use-case/purpose of your (so called URL) `user` with value `AAA% BBB@DDD.COM` it could finally represent part of an URL or email-address.

In your special case, said:

> **populate the form field** relative to the username. Model-variable `user` does not contain a valid email-address. It is used in conjunction with an *alias system* already installed by the customer. So *aliasing* will work this way.

Let's suppose the end-user which does later edit the form-field is responsible of making it valid (or a script does this validation).

Anyway bear in mind that an internet-address (like URL/email) **needs some validation**:

- either before written to the final HTML (using Java or Freemarker)
- or after being further processed inside your web-page (using JavaScript).

Otherwise it could possibly not yield the desired effect.

### See also

Related questions:

- [Is there any way to url decode variable on Freemarker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073601/is-there-any-way-to-url-decode-variable-on-freemarker)
- [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters#10786112)

Comment: It seems that my case is similar to userA.
From Java i do Export "AAA% BBB@DDD.COM", on URL i do have "AAA%25+BBB@DDD.COM", what i need to print on html is again "AAA% BBB@DDD.COM"

Comment: Thanks, in my case it works fine this way <#if myCase??>value = "${user}"</#if>

Comment: It has nothing to do with FreeMarker, it doesn't do any such magic. Auto-escaping escapes characters special to HTML (`<` `&` `>` `"` `'`) when you print something with `${...}`, and that's it. It doesn't care about `%`, `=`, etc.

Comment: @ddekany: Thanks for your feedback. I updated my answer. Hopefully more comprehensible and helpful to others!

Comment: @hc_dev Yes, now it's correct. Just as a side note (not related to the original question), without auto-escaping on, this will break if `value` contains `"`: `value="${user}"`. If auto-escaping (or `#escape`) is not used, the safe form is this: `value="${user?html}"`.